# I can not dynamically GoToState in WPF. What is wrong?

Tags: wpf, blend, visualstatemanager

I created the simplest WPF application with Blend for Visual Studio.

I created the simplest visual state groups for a single textbox:

My problem is that I can not dynamically GoToState using this code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox.MouseEnter+=new System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler(textBox_MouseEnter);
}
private void textBox_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // This will be an empty list
    var states = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(textBox);
    // This will be false
    bool thisReturnsFalse =   VisualStateManager.GoToState(textBox, "VisualState1", true);
}
```

This is my XAML:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
        <VisualState x:Name="VisualState">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBox">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFE40404"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="VisualState1">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBox">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF23FF00"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
            <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="VisualState1"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
            <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="VisualState"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `VisualStateGroups` are not defined in the `TextBox`, so the call

```
var states = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(textBox);
```

won't return what you expect. If you want to get the defined states, pass the `FrameworkElement` that contains the `VisualStateGroups` (I'm assuming the `Window` here):

```
var states = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this);
```

The same should probably be used for the call to `VisualStateManager.GoToState`:

```
bool shouldReturnTrue = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "VisualState1", true);
```

Comment: My call for GoToState is from an event. I had to move the VisualStateGroups in TextBox on my XAML and now I get:
    /* This is 1 as expected: */
    var stateGroups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(textBox);
    /* This is still false: */
    bool thisReturnsFalse = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "VisualState1", false); /* Also my KeyUp, KeyDown does not work */

Comment: @profimedica update your XAML to reflect those changes, as the XAML in your question doesn't show that.

Comment: @profimedica Try calling GoToElementState instead of GoToState

Comment: When I replace 'this' with the grid name in my original code and use GoToElementState on that grid, it will work. It also work using the button name and having the VisualStateGroups defined in the button. Other attempts were not successfull. Now, I need to use GoToElementState on a template. In my oppinion, this function will have a better implementation in next release.